# Value not passed to $1 - .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.Domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.Domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://Domain.com/FolderName/$1 [L]
```

When I type in `SubDomain.DomainsName.com` it is redirected to `DomainName.com/FolderName`, but I want it to be `DomainName.com/FolderName/SubDomain`

The SubDomain is not passed to $1, any ideas to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one mistake `$1` has to be `%1`.

From :[RewriteCond <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> - RewriteRule backreferences: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions..
> - RewriteCond backreferences: These are backreferences of the form %N (1 <= N <= 9), which provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.Domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.Domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://Domain.com/FolderName/%1 [L]
```

Comment: When I `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` it gives me /FolderName/ .  The result I am looking for is /FolderName/SubDomain
Ain't working with %1 too